# How to find if a dataset is affected by another dataset?

Tags: dataset, data-mining

i am pretty new into this data mining. I have 2 dataset which is Human Development Index and Life Expectancy Index and i want to know if the Life Expectancy dataset is affectting the value of HDI dataset. What is the best way to know that? Thank You

The HDI Datasets look like this:
[image]

The Life Expectancy Dataset look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to **join** these two data sets.

That may involve gathering additional data to fill missing values, or to discard some data points that were only present in one of the data sets. Because the join key may differ, you may need to also construct a mapping between the two keys.

Comment: i've tried to join the datasets using Pandas `pd.merge()`, but i only get the csv header which is the year and 0 rows. any suggestion?

Comment: Because your data's is not in the required shape. Pivot your data appropriately first. To join, you need to have a proper **join key**.